# Dereferencing pointer problem in C++ Static Inheritance?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use static polymorphism, but I get compile-time warnings and segmentation fault error.What is wrong?

Compiler: arm-linux-g++ (GCC) 4.4.2

Warning: dereferencing pointer ‘this.123’ does break strict-aliasing rules,
warning: dereferencing pointer ‘this.124’ does break strict-aliasing rules

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include "extlib.h" ///void ledFunc(uint32_t state);

template<typename T>
class BaseLed {
public:
    explicit BaseLed(){}
    virtual ~BaseLed() {}

    void turnOn(){static_cast<T*>(this)->trunOn();}
    void turnOff(){static_cast<T*>(this)->trunOff();}
};

class Led: public BaseLed<Led>{
public:
    typedef void (*LedFuncPtr)(uint32_t);

    Led():
        BaseLed<Led>(), mLedSetPtr{ledFunc}
    {}
    virtual ~Led(){}

    void trunOn(){ mLedFuncPtr(1); }
    void trunOff(){ mLedFuncPtr(0); }

private:
    LedFuncPtr mLedFuncPtr;

};

int main() {
    BaseLed<Led> led;
    led.turnOn();
    sleep(2);
    led.turnOn();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. You also have typos: `trunOn` and `trunOff`

Comment: `led` is not a `Led`, it's a `BaseLed<Led>`.

Comment: `led` is an object of class `BaseLed<Led>`, but inside `turnOn()`, you convert its `this` pointer into `Led*`. That does not make any sense. There is no object of class `Led` anywhere involved.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error (after fixing more typos) https://godbolt.org/z/o4Kzj3

Comment: @idclev463035818 But that code is wrong IMO. How can you use an object of a base class as an object of a derived class? You call a member function from derived which manipulates a member from derived, but this member does not exist in the base.

Comment: @DanielLangr yes it is wrong. But that is definitely not the code that OP got a segfault with and the warning I also dont see

Comment: @idclev463035818 I believe the behavior is undefined, so we cannot make any assumption about reproduction.

Comment: @idclev463035818 This has undefined behaviour and doesn't require either segfault or diagnostic.

Comment: @molbdnilo ub or not, my point is only: the code as posted wont compile (it has hard errors not only a warning)

Comment: @DanielLangr calling a method called `turnOn` via `trunOn` is not ub, its an error ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 Don't understand. How could a compiler know whether the casted pointer points to an object of a base or derived class?

Comment: @DanielLangr it doesnt, but a compiler will find other errors in the posted code and I am curious how to get the warning reported by OP

Answer (score 4):

`led` is not a `Led`, it's a `BaseLed<Led>`.

In `turnOn` and `turnOff`, you can only dereference the casted pointer if `*this` really is an object of type `T`, and it's not.
Since it’s not, the behaviour is undefined.

This is the same situation, but without templating:

```
struct A
{
    void foo();
};

struct B: A
{
    void bar() {}
};

void A::foo()
{
    static_cast<B*>(this)->bar();
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.foo();
}
```

You need an object of the proper type:

```
int main() {
    Led led;
    led.turnOn();
    sleep(2);
    led.turnOn();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to [@molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63010031/11471113):

Since led is of type `BaseLed<Led>`, it does not contain `mLedFuncPtr`. When you call `BaseLed<Led>::TurnOn()`. The object first get converted to type `LED`, call `Led::TrunOn()`, and then modify `mLedFuncPtr`. However, like as I said, `LED` does not contain `mLedFuncPtr`, so it is accessing garbage data and result in segfault.

Comment: `Led::TurnOn()` does not modify `mLedFuncPtr`. It just invokes the function it points to.